# Migrate mx record from godaddy to AWS EC2 without Route53

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, mx-record

Guys please help me is it possible to use my own domain hosted in godaddy and point it to ec2 without Route53

Comment: yes, it is possible

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding, you can add `mx` records in Godaddy itself to your `EC2` server IP address, if you have multiple servers better to use `ELB` in front of them and use its `provided DNS name`. in your case you should **NOT** customize your `name servers` (leave them `default` to be managed by Godaddy, in name server section you should have couple of records like this `nsXX.domaincontrol.com`)

Hint: In case of a **default** `VPC`, it is recommended to have an [Elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) for your `EC2` to make sure you have a **static** IP address for your `EC2` instance (not to be changed in case of shutdown/restart)

If you launched your `EC2` instance in **custom** `VPC`, you should have launched your EC2 instance in a `public subnet` (routings through `internet gateway`) and also you must have an Elastic IP address too only in this case.

If I understood wrongly, please leave a comment and I will be glad to update the answer.